# Sci Fi novel about humanity being trapped in a VR universe by an AI... with murder parties

Tags: story-identification, novel, virtual-worlds

I recently read Scott Barlett's *Unsung* book, which reminded me of a book I've been trying to track back down for a few decades.

Essentially, it was an ebook (which I *think* was self-published on the writer's website, though this is going back about 20 years), centered around the idea that a newborn computer/AI had gained the ability to manipulate reality, and therefore decided to pull all of humanity into a VR universe, where they'd be safe from harm.  I've got vague memories of it basically transforming an entire planet into the hardware required to run said simulation and host all of humanity.

The main character was a woman, who'd been the first person "saved" by the computer - she was dying of old age in a hospital bed when it first started to explore it's powers, and it basically reset/rebuilt her body so that she was back to being in peak "adult-aged" condition.

And the book starts with her attending a "murder party", in which participents get killed in various gruesome ways - something which has become popular among the increasingly jaded population, since the computer will just heal and resurrect them immediately after death.  However, she decides that the party is boring and kills herself quickly to get back out of it.

From there, she ends up working with the man who built the AI/computer, and (without wanting to put too many spoilers in this) they end up seemingly alone on a prehistoric planet.

It was certainly a book with pretty dark/mature themes - in some ways, it reminded me of the writings of Iain M. Banks or Jack L. Chalker, both of whom dabbled with VR-based stories at times and often explored some very dark paths!

And I'm curious as to whether there were any sequels, since it definitely ended at an interesting point in the story...

Comment: This has been closed as a Duplicate, but please don't be discouraged, or feel this is a bad question. It's just one that's been asked before, and our policy is to close questions as duplicates in this case. You will still receive points for any votes made on your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[The Metamorphosis of Prime Intellect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Metamorphosis_of_Prime_Intellect)*, a novella by Roger Williams.

> The story of the novella explores the nature of human desire and the uses and abuses of technology in the satisfaction of desire. The story begins after "the Change", in a dream-like post-scarcity society, approximately six hundred years in the future, in which humans have godlike control over their environments, made possible by the supercomputer called Prime Intellect. Prime Intellect operates under Isaac Asimov's three laws of robotics, which, according to its own interpretation, allow temporary voluntary harm and discomfort. PI has made humanity immortal and satisfies nearly every whim.
>
> Caroline, the thirty-seventh oldest living human being, engages in a sport known as "death jockeying", whose players die elaborately and painfully for sport before being resurrected by Prime Intellect.
>
> Flashbacks set before the Change show the creation of Prime Intellect by Lawrence, a technologist, and its realization of its power, and the past life of Caroline before and after the Change, which happened not gradually but rapidly.
>
> In the present, Caroline makes use of a "Death Contract", an understanding between a person and Prime Intellect that the person is not to be removed from danger until the instant of death (at which point the person is fully restored, as allowing a person to die permanently would violate Prime Intellect’s inherent ethics based on Asimov’s laws). Caroline makes use of a Death Contract, as well as her own powers of persuasion, in order to trick a pre-Change enemy into torturing herself into psychosis as an act of revenge.
>
> After learning that Prime Intellect had destroyed distant alien life as a possible threat to humanity, and having been herself deeply dissatisfied with her post-Change life, Caroline decides to meet Lawrence and confront him. After an arduous journey, she reaches him only to discover that he has no real control over Prime Intellect's actions. Through their discussions, she figures out a way to force Prime Intellect to undo the Change, and does so, with Lawrence's help. They find themselves naked and young on Earth, completely barren of humanity and man-made objects. They decide to trek to the Ozarks, where they have several children and try to repopulate the human race. Forty-two years after the fall of Prime Intellect, Lawrence dies. Seventy-three years after the fall, Caroline dies, telling the story of Prime Intellect and cyberspace to her oldest daughter but swearing her to secrecy.

Comment: I was familiar with this because I asked about it before at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125496/short-story-about-a-virtual-world-protagonist-is-a-female-who-specializes-in-to

Comment: Blimey.  I'm genuinely impressed that it was tracked down so quickly!  I must admit that I'd forgotten about the Death Contract side of things, though I did remember what had happened to the people who had become too jaded with life.

Many thanks for that!

Comment: :) As I said, I'd asked about it before, so I recognized it when I read the description.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots That was the first question I ever answered on here.  And then I immediately misplaced the FarfieldDino account credentials I had just created.

Comment: @baronet_canid: [You should be able still to merge them](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/03/we-now-support-multiple-openids/).